# I receive file URL as response from API. When user clicks on download button, the file should be downloaded without opening file preview in a new tab

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot

How to achieve this in react js?

I am new and I only know this way to get any file downloaded, Can anyone suggest a better method.

```
<a href={uploadedFileLink} target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" download>
<Button>
  <i className="fas fa-download"/>
  Download File
</Button>
</a>
```

Comment: `target="_blank"` tells browser to open in a new tab or window. Have you tried `target="_self"` or `target="_parent"`? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a

Comment: I haven't tried but thanks for the response. I will try it